# get HTML of created element in VueJS to use JQuery

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have default list of users and button add user which will added user to list.
Users which created by pushed button i want to marked as red background at once user added to list.
To make it im use

> this.$watch("list", function() {
>
> > ```
> >  this.$nextTick(function() {
> >    var index = this.list.length - 1;
> >    $(".wrapper .user:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('red');
> >  });
> > ```
> >
> > });

It's works fine while user delete. When click to delete index var affcted previuosly rows.
https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/37/
How to reproduce:
click Add item. Then delete created item. Tony will have red background but i need red background for created users only.

How can i get html of created element and work with jquery only in created element HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, any change to the `list` variable causes the last item to be coloured red. You could fix the problem by putting

```
 this.$nextTick(function() {
   var index = this.list.length - 1;
   $(".wrapper .user:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('red');
 });
```

in your `addItems` method.

But, instead, I would suggest adding a flag to your list that indicates if an item is new. Then, use that flag to determine  if the item should be coloured red.

```js
var listing = Vue.extend({
  template: '#users-template',
  data: function () {
    return {
      list: [],
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.loadItems();
  },
  methods: {
   itemClass: function(item) {
     return item.isNew ? 'red' : '';
    },
    loadItems: function() {
      this.list = [
       {
          name: 'mike',
          isNew: false,
        },
        {
         name: 'arnold',
          isNew: false,
        },
        {
         name: 'tony',
          isNew: false
        }
      ];
    },
    addItems: function() {
      this.list.push({
       name: 'Viktor',
        isNew: true
      });
    },
    removeItemUser: function (item) {
      this.list.splice(this.list.indexOf(item), 1)
    },
  }
});


Vue.component('listing', listing);
var app = new Vue({
  el: ".lists-wrappers",
});
```

```css
.user{border: 1px solid; cursor: pointer}
.red{background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0-rc.3/vue.js"></script>
<div class="lists-wrappers">
  <listing></listing>
</div>
      
<template id="users-template">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button @click="addItems()">Add item</button>
    <div  v-for="item in list"  :class="['user', itemClass(item)]">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
      <button class="destroy" @click="removeItemUser(item)">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need html to call JQuery functions and plugins for new  html  which added by addItem() method.

Comment: Did you try putting your `this.$nextTick` code in the addItem() method?

Comment: Looks like it was browser issue when i tried to use  this.$nextTick code in the addItem() method. Thanks for reply.